# InflateException with Custom RecyclerView in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, inflate-exception

For a project of mine, I wanted to build a custom recyclerview. So, I have extended the RecyclerView the following way:

```
class MyCustomRecyclerView : RecyclerView {

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context){
        initializationCode(context)
    }
    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : super(context, attrs){
        initializationCode(context)
    }
    ...
}
```

For the sake of brevity, I excluded the most parts of the custom RecyclerView. As you can see, I also added the required constructors as secondary constructors in Kotlin.
Especially, the constructor with the `AttributeSet` which is crucial for such custom view implementations. Now, the XML that gets inflated looks like this:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="postListViewModel"
            type="com.celik.abdullah.myproject.viewmodels.PostFragmentViewModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".ui.fragments.PostFragment">

        <com.celik.abdullah.myproject.util.MyCustomRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/custom_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:padding="6dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:postListData="@{postListViewModel.postList}"
            tools:listitem="@layout/post_list_item">

        </com.celik.abdullah.myproject.util.MyCustomRecyclerView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Process: com.celik.abdullah.myproject, PID: 4282
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.celik.abdullah.myproject.util.MyCustomRecyclerView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class com.celik.abdullah.myproject.util.MyCustomRecyclerView
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
        at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
        at com.celik.abdullah.myproject.ui.fragments.PostFragment.onCreateView(PostFragment.kt:35)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2600)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Can someone help ?

Comment: Can you include more details of `MyCustomRecyclerView`? At this point it seems ok to me

Comment: It looks like your initializationCode throws exception during inflation. InvocationTargetException wraps en exceptions thrown by constructor.

Comment: please post the `PostFragmentViewModel` class

Comment: @Bracadabra: Thank you. Indeed, I had a NullPointerException with a variable that had a nullable type. I solved that. And now, it works.

Comment: Cool, then I will copy a comment not to leave the question open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your initializationCode throws exception during inflation. InvocationTargetException wraps en exceptions thrown by constructor.

Comment: Again, thank you. After reading your answer I looked at the stacktrace more closely and find also that a NullPointerException was thrown first and then the InflateException. After solving the NullPointerException, the InflateException was not thrown any more.

Comment: i have same issue kindly explain in simple way that i can understand thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You're using `layoutManager` property and you're setting `androidx`'s **LinearLayoutManager**

```
app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Try removing this from XML and set it from Kotlin file dynamically

Do double check if you are extending `RecyclerView` in `MyCustomRecyclerView` from `androidx`'s `RecyclerView` or not.

As, `RecyclerView` is available outside `androidx` also

Please check [androidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/recyclerview) and [withoutAndroidX](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView) version for reference